# Where in the database file is an index rebuild started? Alternative to SHRINKFILE?

Tags: sql-server, index, disk-space

When rebuilding an index in SQL server, where in the datafile does it put that data?

Does it start at the beginning of free space and fill in the gaps from there?

Context:  I have some large .ndf files I'm trying to shrink (not important why); but instead of using a SHRINKFILE command, I'm wondering if I can rebuild the indexes and then truncate the file from 80GB down to 25GB.

Edit:  There are many reasons to want to reduce the file space or reorganize it logically.  These may relate to fragmentation, how that fragmentation is translated to IO requests, moving large files across a network, swapping out storage space, how data is read sequentially, etc.  Excessive space usage could even prevent other files from being written to your disk that need the space or dbs that need room to grow.  You might have done some testing and now need to clean up excessive data and the space it required.  Imagine you just switched to a newer database server and could take a 400GB database and compress it down to 100GB with newly available db management techniques, compression, etc,  That's got value and I'm sure there are many other scenarios where this matters.  Just be careful to judge the reasons behind questions please.

Comment: You know if you shrink the file it will grow again, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that, and fragmentation, and moving data to other file groups as an option, etc.  I mentioned to ignore those concerns above.   Please be careful not to judge the merits of a question because it might suggest a bad practice.  It kind of devalues it even if you mean well.

Comment: Forgive me, but most people I come across (including future readers of this question) who are asking about shrinking files don't realize how expensive (and pointless) it is to shrink only to grow again. So it's not fair to just say "oh, don't worry about that, I know what I'm doing." Future readers don't. I'm not judging the question, I'm just making sure that's clear to anyone who comes across it, since the spirit of this entire network is to help more than just the single person asking the question.

Comment: I think most professionals are asking what for? Rather than why.  **Is there a problem you are solving?** It’s not lack of interest, it is just that often this requires way more steps to implement for such little gain. Most problems are design issue, architectural technical debt that led to this. Also consider a Production Server, you would have to test on your Cert before going live...but what of refreshes from prod? I have a box where simply moving a number of large blob data would require 3-5hrs of downtime...if I only did this once! We decided to start from scratch and design right. 

Comment: I hear you Aaron. They want us to keep questions short and sweet but do you think then there is value in adding that sort of disclaimer or caution to the questions themselves?  In this case there is already lots of content recognizing that specific concern already both in stack and elsewhere.

Comment: Who is "they"? Where do you see this? Questions shouldn't be books but they should contain enough detail that the problem can be understood and solved. If they don't include that detail, expect questions like mine.

Comment: @Clifton_h,  thanks, in my case, I'm testing a migration of our data from an older SQL version that didn't support page compression, partitioning, column-store, etc.  We have several very large tables in our database ~500 Million rows that after compression, partitioning, archiving where appropriate, and in some cases different index structures, etc leaves a lot of extra space.  Because this is also in the cloud we pay for that premium disk space and would love to not pay more than necessary at the outset.  And it's also just an interesting question for me.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe those details are documented anywhere, and even if you were to figure it out (by asking Paul Randal, or perhaps by mapping the exact pages before and after an index rebuild), you may not be able to rely on those going forward. You also might end up with some random single pages at the end of the file anyway, and still need to do a shrink.

The best idea, in my opinion, is to [do an index rebuild into a different file group](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/):

> - Create a new filegroup
> - Move all affected tables and indexes into the new filegroup using the CREATE INDEX … WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON) ON syntax, to move the tables and remove fragmentation from them at the same time
> - Drop the old filegroup that you were going to shrink anyway (or shrink it way down if its the primary filegroup)

If that's not an option, then you can instead do a shrink-then-reindex, or maybe a reindex-shrink-reindex:

1. Initial reindex: this releases free space *within* each page, and might be necessary if you've made major changes in the table structure like dropping large columns or changing column datatypes
2. ShrinkFile (never use ShrinkDatabase): Pick a reasonable target size, shrink each file with some remaining free space (I usually pick 15-20% free)
3. Final reindex: Resolves any fragmentation we created in step 2.

This multi-pass approach is a ton of IO, and might take a while to do. That's why the single-pass approach into a different file group is preferred, if you can pre-allocate the space.

Also, the final reindex may reclaim some of the space recovered in step 2. This is common where the majority of space is taken up by a single huge table or single huge index.